# Is it correct to say "Can you put your school supplies into your backpack"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

I want my daughter to put her ruler, 2 pencils, 1 eraser and a book into her backpack.

Do we have a general word to refer these things?

I thought of "**stuff**" but it is too informal.

Can I say "**Can you put your school supplies into your backpack**"?

But "**school supplies**" sounds too much for some simple things above.

Comment: Why not just 'school things' or 'things for school'?

Comment: It's probably better with a small child to be more specific, as they may not know what to take or may forget something, but failing that, Weather Vane's "things" is fine.

Comment: _School supplies_ would be things sold by a company for use in schools, not an individual person's belongings.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with your sentence, but it does seem a bit formal for a parent-child interaction.  How about:

> Please pack up your backpack.

Or

> Please get your backpack ready for school.

As an aside, I tried to avoid asking questions of my kids when I was actually making requests.